# Display all records in Ajax

Tags: ajax

I am trying to get the records from JSON file, 
the results showing only the first data..could you please help how can I show all the records in table a tr

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'records.json'
}).done(function(data){
    $('#content1').text(data[0].id);
    $('#content2').text(data[0].date);
    $('#content3').text(data[0].description);
    $('#content4').text(data[0].amount);
});
```

Comment: look loop in javascript and replace 0 in data[0] by index

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/